# Where does 'SOURCE' file come from in Firefox Dev Tools Debugger?

Tags: web-scraping, reverse-engineering, web-frontend

Using Firefox's Web Developer Tools and loading up the homepage from say https://www.espn.com , I switch to the Debugger tab and see this:

[image: 1 - espn.com w/firefox dev tools on debugger tab]

If I try to 'Find in Files' (Ctrl+Shift+F) in Dev Tools, say for 'data-id', I get results like this:

[image: dev tools search results]

My question is about the results like the two that list as '(1 match)' with no source file name. If I click a result from one of them, I jump to a 'SOURCE' file like this:

[image: example SOURCE file]

Generically asking (only using espn.com as an example) what is this 'SOURCE' file content of, what generates it, etc? I'm looking to better understand how particular websites supply dynamic content to their pages and find the information I'm interested in is found in these type of results/'files'. But without an understanding of them, it is unclear how I might be able to request/generate/scrape for them.

(Also, I notice that only Firefox's Dev Tools shows these type of generated (assumed) files, Chrome doesn't.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may produce this by several means:

`new Function(content)` does this (which is the one ESPN website uses)

```js
new Function(`const unique_string="_AAAAA_"; console.log(unique_string)`)();
```

```html
Go to Firefox's dev-tools' debugger and search for the unique string
```

`eval(content)` does this too

```js
new Function(`const unique_string="_BBBBB_"; console.log(unique_string)`)();
```

```html
Go to Firefox's dev-tools' debugger and search for the unique string
```

so does `Element#append(Range#createContextualFragment("<script>"+content+"<\/script>")`

```js
document.body.append(
  document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
    `<script>const unique_string="_CCCCC_"; console.log(unique_string)<\/script>`
  )
);
```

```html
Go to Firefox's dev-tools' debugger and search for the unique string
```

and maybe others I don't think of right now.
(To say the truth I find it a bit surprising that something like `setTimeout(content)` doesn't produce one).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This makes sense to me on ESPN and other sites of interest.

I was hoping the SOURCE content was generated by the minified javascripts preloaded by the webpage and then updated the DOM/html itself. Setting DOM breakpoints didn't reveal anything like this. Also doing a simple 'curl' GET request shows me that the content of interest is already in the webpage itself - SOURCE files appear to generate off the HTML instead.